# How to initilize a variant type class member to monostate

Tags: c++, variant, monostate

In the example below, how would I construct the node object for data = monostate ??

```
class node : public header
{
    using value_type = variant<monostate, string, deque<string>>;

    value_type data;

public:
    template <typename T>
    node(timePoint since_, timeDuration timeout_, T data_)
        : header(since_, timeout_), data(data_) {}
    ~node() = default;

    inline value_type &get_data() { return data; };
};
```

Comment: `auto node = node(foo, bar, std::monostate{});`?

Comment: =P yes, it works!